# Program that gives Wikidata identifier from Wiki* article name

Tags: open-source, wikidata

Getting the Wikidata id of a Wikipedia/Wikivoyage/Wiktionary article (in a particular language) is easy to do using the Wikidata API, but takes too much time when you have thousands of ids to find.

Is there a program that could do the hard work for me, and be efficient for large volumes?

It could possibly work by downloading http://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/latest/wikidatawiki-latest-wb_items_per_site.sql.gz or similar and wither parse it directly or load it into a database.

Requirements:

- Works for all languages/projects (for instance Italian Wikivoyage, Japanese Wiktionary, etc)
- Open source
- Command line
- Answers each request in less than 100ms (except the first, which downloads data)
- Possibility to reset the data (when I think it is outdated)

Comment: BTW, using the API, you can get up to 50 articles using a single request (or 500, if you have a bot account on Wikidata).

Comment: @svick: I might end up doing this, as `wikidatawiki-latest-wb_items_per_site.sql` takes days to load into MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was provided this week in a Wikidata-l thread: use Magnus' [linked items](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/linked_items.php) or [Wikidata Reconcile](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-reconcile/) for OpenRefine.

## Linked items: usage

Enter `[[Paris]] [[Rome]] [[Sofia]]`, press the button, and you get `Q90 Q220 Q472`.

Comment: Linked items is great, but are you sure Wikidata Reconcile can be used for this? `https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-reconcile/?queries={"query"%3A"Rome"%2C"query"%3A"Paris"}` does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for adding a more specific example, sorry for being unclear. As for Wikidata Reconcile, it has to be used from within OpenRefine AFAIK; didn't test yet.